# Firing function on focus or blur(together)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to be able to do something when the input get focus or lose it(both event).

I tried the following, but this works separately(when coded separately) by event: only on focus, or only on losing focus.

Also, I want it cross platform as possible(including touch devices), would this be enough(focus and blur) or there is some other events I need to care?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div id="zzz" class=""></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

jQuery(3.2.1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Also tried using: $(".inp").focus.blur(function() {
    $(".inp").on("keypress", "focus", "blur", function () {
       if ( !$(this).val() ) {
           $("#zzz").removeClass("one");
       }
       else {
           $("#zzz").addClass("one");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this is -

You have to change this -

```
$(".inp").on("keypress", "focus", "blur", function () {
```

to

```
$(".inp").on("keypress focus blur", function () {
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Also tried using: $(".inp").focus.blur(function() {
    $(".inp").on("keypress focus blur", function () {
       if ( !$(this).val() ) {
           $("#zzz").removeClass("one");
       }
       else {
           $("#zzz").addClass("one");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div id="zzz" class=""></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I was close :)

Answer (score 0):

Give all the event listeners separately and invoke a function on them it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inp").on("keypress",function () {
   doSomething();
    });
    $(".inp").on("focus",function () {
   doSomething();
    });
    $(".inp").on("blur",function () {
   doSomething();
    });
});

function doSomething()
{
       if ( !$(".inp").val() ) {
           $("#zzz").removeClass("one");
       }
       else {
           $("#zzz").addClass("one");
       }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div id="zzz" class=""></div>
```

**OR**
If you really want to combine all the events then follow the below approach:

```
$('#element').on('keypress blur focus', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});
```

See the code example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inp').on('keypress blur focus', doSomething);
});

function doSomething()
{
       if ( !$(".inp").val() ) {
           $("#zzz").removeClass("one");
       }
       else {
           $("#zzz").addClass("one");
       }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
.one {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp">
<div id="zzz" class=""></div>
```

Comment: I would suggest `$('#element').on('keypress blur focus', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});` approach. Actually it depends on what you want to achieve. There are not major differences.